# Is this sub-Gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, empirical-processes

Say $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d. sub-Gaussian variables following the definition in [High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#). Denote $X = (X_1, X_2)^T$, and $\eta$ is some positive constant. Is the following random variable still sub-Gaussian? How to prove it rigorously?
$$\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}^2, ||t||_2\leq \eta} X^Tt$$
I guess the proof may need to use techniques in empirical processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use any empirical process techniques here. Note that

$$
\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}^2, \| t \|_2 \leq \eta} X^T t =
\frac{1}{\eta} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}^2, \| t \|_2 \leq 1} X^t t =
\frac{1}{\eta} \| (X_1, X_2) \|_2,
$$

which is the Euclidean norm of a random vector with subgaussian coordinates.

Chapter 3 in the same book covers random vectors with subgaussian coordinates.